# IIS6: Create/install SSL self-signed cert from command line

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6, ssl-certificate

I want to automate the setup of SSL for a website in IIS6.  It appears selfSSL and certutil can be used to do this but certificates are new to me and I'm unsure how to put them together.

From what I understand I need to:

1. create a certificate
2. assign the certificate to the website
3. add a secure (SSL/443) binding to the website

I would also like to avoid creating a new certificate if the site cert has already been created.  That way I don't end up with a bunch of redudant certs.

Comment: Do you already have a certificate or do you want a new certificate for each individual server?

Comment: This is a great question and I look forward to hearing the answers.  One thing I would warn towards is the use of SelfSSL, especially with multiple sites in one instance of IIS.  In my experience it has been ok with a single site at a time.  I believe there is a workaround for the issue and even an updated tool that does not have the bug (SSLDiag?).  There are more details on the issue in the following blog comment thread - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/04/20/selfssl-bug-with-websites.aspx#413765

Comment: Lee - I want a new certificate. I found selfSSL appears to provide this via commandline

Saul - Thanks for that info!  We will probably use selfSSL (or something similiar) for our dev/sqa/mock environments but manual creation for production.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the IIS 6 Resource Kit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17275

There is a tool in the resource kit called [selfssl.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671#11) - it automates the creation, assignment and even trusting of the newly created certificate. We use it quite a bit where I work to ensure that our dev boxes have certificates we can use during testing/development.

Here is the command line we use - it will create the cert (for localhost) using a key-size of 1024, trust it, and make it valid for ~10 years:

```
selfssl.exe /T /N:CN=localhost /K:1024 /V:3650
```

If you are hosting multiple sites, you will need to use the `/S` parameter to specify the site id you want to add the certificate to.

Note: this also works like a champ with IIS 5 on WinXP, but I have never tried it on any of the IIS 7 family.

Comment: is it support TSL1.2 as newly it seem to be needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html) for authoring your setup, then running this [CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) (which simply runs **SelfSSL**) will do the trick for you:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallCert" 
              ExeCommand="selfssl.exe /N:CN=fqdn.myserver.com /V:365" /> 

<InstallExecuteSequence> 
    <Custom Action="InstallCert" After="InstallFinalize" /> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**This action will**:

- Generate the certificate
- Install the certificate to `Default Web Site`
- Add the https binding

**Command line explained:**

```
/N:CN=[fully qualified server name]
/V: = Validity in days (365 in my example)
```

You can specify port with `/P:[port number]` switch. The default is 443 which is what you want so you can leave it out.

**Caveat**: There seems to be bug with SelfSSL which seems to have been [resolved](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/04/20/selfssl-bug-with-websites.aspx).

If you still run into it, alternative is to switch to `SSLDiag` tool which has a similar syntax:

```
SSLDiag.exe /selfssl /n:CN=fqdn.myserver.com /v:365
```

I do not have experience with other setup authoring tools (InstallShield etc.) but I'm sure they have provisions to run commandline programs. Worst case, you can run this through a batch file!

Hope this helps.