# IIS Express 10.0: How to create and sign your own certificates from the command line?

Tags: iis, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to configure HTTPS in IIS Express 10.0. Since this version doesn't contain a GUI, I'm at a loss for how to sign my own certificates so that I can secure my local host (and do away with those annoying Chrome browser flags). There are a lot of [great tutorials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/make-your-own-ssl-certificate-for-testing-and-learning.aspx) out there... that [assume you are using a manager GUI](http://I%20have%20experience%20working%20in%20all%20five%20stages%20of%20the%20mobile%20&%20web%20app%20production%20process,%20as%20well%20as%20managing%20the%20business%20operations%20that%20make%20it%20possible.%20My%20past%20work%20includes:%20%20Marketing-oriented%20website%20design%20Sales,%20contracts%20negotiation%20&%20accounts%20management%20Project%20scoping%20&%20user%20story%20creation%20UI%20mockups%20and%20graphics%20collateral%20creation%20Agile/SCRUM-based%20project%20management%20QA%20testing%20&%20app%20store%20deployment%20Personnel,%20technology%20&%20budget%20resource%20management%20I%20am%20seeking%20entry-level%20opportunities%20offering%20future%20growth%20into%20roles%20like%20project%20management,%20UI%20architecture%20design,%20or%20growth%20hacking/business%20development.). If someone could point me to a resource that walks me through the steps for executing the process of creating and signing SSL certs purely through the command line, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Jexus Manager for IIS Express, https://Jexus.codeplex.com You will have to run it as admin.

Comment: I've since discovered that the solution is pretty much the same as the one offered for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084466/iis6-create-install-ssl-self-signed-cert-from-command-line?rq=1. Not sure what the precedent is for marking your own question as a dupe, but I'm flagging mine as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me nearly a month of periodic searches on Google and poring over ancient MSDN help documentation, but I finally hacked together a brute-force solution by binding an SSL certificate to a specific port number via `netsh.exe` commands. Detailed instructions can be found in this MSDN post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx

Note that this post is OLD (only references XP and Vista). I run Windows 7 (using IIS 10.0, as previously mentioned), and I had no conflicts following the Vista instructions. Might not be useful for dev environments running in Windows 8 or 10.